# Rid of repeated spans in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

React renders multiple spans, only with the actual value. Any advice on how to fix this:

[image]

And if it matter, the name of the user isn't suppose to be in a span, but as innerHTML of ".chatUser"

The actual render method is short:

```
createShortUsername: function() {
 // shortName is first two letter of first name. 
 var shortName = this.props.userName.split(" ")[0].slice(0, 2);
 console.log(shortName);
 return shortName;
},
render: function() {
 return (
   <div className="chatUser"> {this.createShortUsername()} </div>
 );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does removing the whitespaces around `{this.createShortUsername()}` do anything? I suspect the spans are added to separate dynamic content (the username) from static content (the whitespaces).

Comment: React wraps any floating text nodes in a span so that it can assign it an ID and quickly refer back to it later during updates and reconciliation. As @ivarni suggested, leading and trailing white spaces can generate empty spans. If this occurs on the server and you don't need the extra markup (so you just want ```<div>shortname</div>```, you can look into [React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponenttostaticmarkup)

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by @ivarni, the extra spans were caused by white spaces!

To prevent this write your code without white spaces around the braced expressions.

```
<ReactElement>{noRoomForWhiteSpace}</ReactElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually some special characters(non visible in your editor) that creeps into the code.(Likely if you had copy-pasted). For me it was `\u2028`. Check the generated javascript file to see what extra characters got into the code. 
To get rid of it, you could remove the line that caused it and type it again( as opposed to copying and pasting)