# How to get value when React wraps content in spans?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that renders some html like below, with one callback method (`this.deleteItem`) triggered upon click of an `x`.  In the callback method, I try to get the content associated with each of the two refs like this

```
var date = this.refs.date.getDomNode.value;
var content = this.refs.content.getDomNode.value;
```

but the result is `undefined` in both cases. When I simply do `this.refs.content.getDomNode` (instead of looking for the value) it shows me a div with some `span` tags inside, and inside of one of those is the content I was seeking. Similarily with the `date` ref, it is a `<small></small>` element with spans inside.

Question: how to get the value/content from a div or element when react wraps content in spans?

```
<div ref="wrapperdiv">
  <span className="delete" onClick={this.deleteItem}>x</span>
  <small ref="date"> {date} </small>
  <div ref="content"> {content } </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of react, in that it wraps any floating text nodes in a span because it has to handle the `data-reactid` of the component. See this [question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469474/how-to-ouput-text-in-reactjs-without-wrapping-it-in-span).

Perhaps if you tried to remove the white space around the content?

```
<div ref="wrapperdiv">
  <span className="delete" onClick={this.deleteItem}>x</span>
  <small ref="date">{date}</small>
  <div ref="content">{content}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also try:

```
this.refs.content.getDomNode().children[0].textContent
```

to get the value of the span.  (Not sure if there is a react specific function for this).  This will have to be done as well as removal of the white space within:

```
<small ref="date">{date}</small>
<div ref="content">{content}</div>
```

This is important because react generates span tags to handle the data-reactid.  Take a look at: [Rid of repeated spans in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501792/rid-of-repeated-spans-in-react-js).