# ReactJS creating extra spans in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have started working on a project and inherited a large amount of ReactJS that I am trying to sort through and better understand.  Currently there is a small issue I'm trying to fix in the app I'm working on.

Here is the code for the render:

```
render: function() {
return (
  <div className="finish-content-container">
    <div className='finish-instructions'>
      <span>
        {this.props.finishInfo.startpage.instructions || ""}
      </span>
    </div>
    {
    this.props.userData.score && !this.props.finishInfo.finishpage.hideScore ?
    <div className="finish-results">
      <span>{"Your Score: " + (this.props.userData.score || "")}</span>
    </div> : ""
    }
    {
    this.props.finishInfo.finishpage && this.props.finishInfo.finishpage.graph ?
      <div className="finish-graph">
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: processStoredGraph(this.props.finishInfo.finishpage.graph, 250, 450)}}></div>
      </div> : ""
    }
    {
    this.props.userData.score && this.props.finishInfo.finishpage && this.props.finishInfo.finishpage.feedback ?
    <div className='finish-results-feedback'>
      {this._getConditionalText(this.props.finishInfo.finishpage.feedback, this.props.userData.score)}
    </div> : ""
    }
    <div className="finish-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.finishInfo.startpage.content}}></div>
    <div className="finish-button">
      <span onClick={this.props.onClick} className="btn finish">REPLAY</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);
},
```

Here's what is happening: all the logic seems to work fine, but it's creating addition spans in the HTML and those spans are taking up real estate on the page, even when they have no data.

Any thoughts? I can include the HTML output from the page if that's helpful at all.

Comment: there's some odd things in this React; `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` seems like data is not being handled the React way, and you're generating a lot inside the return statement, instead of preparing the content and then simply doing a `return <div>{content}</div>;`, with content being an array of elements that need to show up on the rendered view.

Comment: I agree. I have inherited this code and I'm trying to better understand it. I agree that this isn't the react way. Do you have suggestions on how I can start to rebuild this code to make it more serviceable?

Comment: I'd start with first aggregating the content you like `function render() { content = []; content.push(this.formThing(this.props....)); ... ; return <div>{content}</div>; }` where `formThing` returns `null` if the input is undefined, or a real JSX fragment if there is meaningful input. That lets you figure out what's getting generated in each bit.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: React inserts spans in the DOM for various reasons, including to wrap floating text nodes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470188/380487)), white space (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515169/380487)), and (I think) to set placeholders for components that return `null` from the `render` method, among other things. If this is causing issues for you, it's probably because you're using CSS that operates on all `span` elements, or all `span` elements within the scope of your component. Ditch the CSS, or make it specific to the elements it needs to style, and you should be fine.

In my opinion, React's approach here is in keeping with the intent of the `span` element, which ought to be a layout no-op if not associated with a specific class.